# Restart PlayConsole SBT server

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I'm running a scala playframework app using `sbt run` on intellij console. However, I exited the server using `ctrl+Z` instead of `ctrl+D`. Now, I try to sbt `sbt run` again, but I'm getting following exception:

> `java.net.BindException: Address already in use`

The port is already in use. That means, previous server did not exited. If I try sbt run with different port `sbt run 9999` other than default 9000, the server starts without any exception. 
So, is there any way to restart or end previous session so that I will not get any binding failed exception if I run the project again?

Comment: ps auxxw | grep sbt

Comment: kill -9 SbtProcessId   or try pkill sbt

Comment: I would assume you should do this different on windows platform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have another process already on that port you are using. You need to `kill` it or use another port.

You can `list` the process that are using the port and then `kill` them

```
use lsof -i:portnumber(8080)
```

Then kill the process using that port `kill PID`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this simple solution. Before, I was looking for pid for sbt, however, it turns to be some java instance. And thank for the lsof cmd. I was unware about that.